# Ошибка в сортировке C++ builer

Tags: c++, c++builder

Почему сортирует строки StringGrid через раз?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    Edit1->Text = "5";
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
    int n;

    n = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);

    StringGrid1->ColCount = n;

    StringGrid1->RowCount = n;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    randomize();
    int i, j, n;
    n = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    for(i = 0;i <= n;i++) {
        j = 0;
        for(j = 0;j <= n;j++) {
            StringGrid1->Cells[i][j] = random(100);
        }
    }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i, j, k, n, foo;
    n = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    for(k = 0;k <= n;k++) {
        for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if(StringGrid1->Cells[j][k] > StringGrid1->Cells[j + 1][k]) {
                    foo = StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[j][k]); //change for elements
                    StringGrid1->Cells[j][k] = StringGrid1->Cells[j + 1][k];
                    StringGrid1->Cells[j + 1][k] = foo;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Осваивать сортировку пузырьком надо, имхо, на обычных массивах. А в более сложном коде использовать готовые алгоритмы из библиотек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас память портится из за заезда за границы массивов. В циклах у вас i становится равна n при заполнении. Дальше возникает неопределенное поведение, что и выглядит как "через раз".

Comment: Смотреть на Button2 CLICK - Это сортировка

Comment: @Vlad - и там тоже есть торжественный заезд за индекс массива.